# SQL average of sums?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database consisting of many tables, 3 tables of interest here are `ThemeParks`, `Tickets` and `TicketPrices`.

I currently have a query which displays the total ticket sales for each country:

```
SELECT SUM(TicketPrices.price) 
FROM TicketPrices, Tickets, ThemeParks
WHERE Tickets.TP_Code = ThemeParks.TP_Code
GROUP BY ThemeParks.TP_country
```

Query Result:

```
SUM(TicketPrices.price)
-----------------------
700
300
300
600
```

I would like to make a query that just displays the average of all of those values. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it inside another query:

```
SELECT AVG(price_sum)
  FROM (SELECT SUM(TicketPrices.price) as price_sum
          FROM TicketPrices, Tickets, ThemeParks 
         WHERE Tickets.TP_Code = ThemeParks.TP_Code 
         GROUP BY ThemeParks.TP_country) t
```

Also, consider switching over to ANSI join syntax.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I found it very helpful! As you probably know, I'm new here and this is my first question and so I haven't figured out how to post code in the code format

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look here to learn how to format your posts: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The average is the sum divided by the count.  So:

```
SELECT SUM(tp.price) / COUNT(DISTINCT tp.TP_COUNTRY)
FROM TicketPrices tp JOIN
     Tickets t
     ON ??? JOIN
     ThemeParks tp
     ON t.TP_Code = tp.TP_Code;
```

The problem with your query, though, is the missing `ON` clause.  You should learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  This will help you write correct queries in the future.  A simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.